# Make the products stay in the cart after logging out

Tags: php

I logged in, added products to the cart and then I logged out (I haven't made the payment yet). The cart is empty after logging in again because I use `session_destroy` in `logout.php`.

Is it possible to make the products stay in the cart even after logging out? If so, how?

Comment: What cart, what framework, what's in your logout.php? You're not giving us much chance to help you.

Comment: It's been solved. Thanks anyway @UlrichSchwarz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Instead of using `session_destroy()` in `logout.php`. You can just unset user login specific values like `unset($_SESSION['user_id'])` or the values you are using for logged in user identification.